# socket.io vs. SignalR

Tags: azure, socket.io, signalr

I am developing a ASP.NET MVC app deployed on Azure, and looking for a library providing asynchronous transport mechanism/fallback.

After my own research, I've concluded that there are two well-known candidates - Socket.io and SignalR.

My question is simple) What's the pros and cons of them? It there any good reason to use one over the other?

thanks :)

Comment: The former is built with the Node.js platform; the latter is for .NET.  Given the technology stack you're already using, the choice seems pretty simple.

Comment: josh3736// what about in performance? is there any difference?

Comment: I couldn't find definitive benchmarks for SignalR, but its [author claims](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx#48b07781-68dd-4ee7-812d-a4cb8e41d54a) somewhere in the neighborhood of 30,000 messages/sec, which is on par with [Socket.io's benchmarks](http://mrjoes.github.com/2011/12/15/sockjs-bench.html#and_for_fun__socketio).

Answer (score 5):

I'd have to say that SignalR is definitely the best approach for your application.  With the current build our laptops serving as servers are pushing around 350k messages/s.  With the next release it will be even higher (several multiples higher judging by current tests).

Check out the main site: http://signalr.net/

The GitHub: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

JabbR for questions: http://jabbr.net/#/rooms/signalr

Comment: How you say SignalR is the best approach? Did you test other pushing server, e.g. Lightstreamer?

Comment: SignalR was built, even tailored, for Asp.NET real-time applications/development, not to mention the post was titled Socket.IO vs. SignalR.

Comment: Where did you read that with the server of the SignalR will push 350k m/s in a common dev pc?

Comment: @N.TaylorMullen They use I/O Completion Ports behind?

Answer (score 2):

I've never used SignalR and according to what google tells me it is a replacement solution for .Net apps.

So I guess you should give it a try.
Socket.IO is awesome, I love it but I'm a noder. According to their doc there is no .net/c# bindings. Maybe their doc is not up to date.

Comment: There are [socket.io *clients* for .NET](http://socketio4net.codeplex.com/), but the server still has to run Node.

Comment: client for .net I'm confused, the aim of socket.IO client is the browser. To do communication between backend they are better tools transport than websockets. Or maybe you for .net desktop app then...

Comment: I've actually used that library to connect a .NET desktop app to a server running Socket.io.

Comment: @josh3736 It makes more sense, and yeah I bet this is a nice tool for that too :)